# XPath translate to lower case not working

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

the xml file looks like

```
<employees>    
 <employee id='1'>
  <Profile_Name>admin</Profile_Name>
  <UserName>user</UserName>
 </employee>

 <employee id='2'>
  <Profile_Name>Admin</Profile_Name>
  <UserName>USER</UserName>
 </employee>

 <employee id='3'>
  <Profile_Name>Adminnn</Profile_Name>
  <UserName>userrrr</UserName>
 </employee>
```

here is my xpath

```
         employees/employee
                     [not(Deleted)]
                       [Profile_Name[last()]
                          [translate(., 
                                     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                                     'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                     )
                          ]
                          =
                           'admin'or 
                           UserName[last()]
                                    [translate(.,
                                               'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                                                'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                              )
                                    ]
                               =
                                'user'
                         ]
```

it should select `employee` elements that don't have `Deleted` child and `Profile_Name` = admin or `UserName`  = userregardless of the case of profileName and UserName

it works fine but don't take character case into consideration.

it should return `employee` with `id` = 1 and 2

Comment: Please, *edit* the question and provide: 1) A complete (but short) XML document; 2) Which exactly nodes must be selected. 3) explanation of the rules for selection.

Comment: HebaEl-Fadly, I edited the question and formatted the XPath expression so it is now readable and understandable. See my answer for an XPath expression that I think selects the nodes you want.

Comment: See the updated answer -- I added XSLT - based verification , which demonstrates that the correct elements are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Right now you have this** (properly formatted to make it readable):

```
           /employees/employee
                     [not(Deleted)]
                       [Profile_Name[last()]
                          [translate(Profile_Name[last()], 
                                     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                                     'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                     )
                          ]
                          =
                           'admin'or 
                           UserName[last()]
                                    [translate(.,
                                               'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                                                'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                              )
                                    ]
                               =
                                'user'
                         ]";
```

**It is obviously wrong** -- the predicates containing `translate()` close too early.

**Probably you want this**:

```
        /employees/employee
                     [not(Deleted)]
                           [translate(Profile_Name[last()], 
                                     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                                     'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                     )
                          =
                           'admin'
                         or 
                           translate(UserName[last()],
                                      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                                      'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                      )
                           =
                            'user'
                            ]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/employees/employee
                     [not(Deleted)]
                           [translate(Profile_Name[last()],
                                     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                     'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                     )
                          =
                           'admin'
                         or
                           translate(UserName[last()],
                                      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                      'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                      )
                           =
                            'user'
                      ]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (based on the provided one, but added more `employee` elements to provide more necessary cases for testing):

```
<employees>
    <employee id='1'>
        <Profile_Name>admin</Profile_Name>
        <UserName>user</UserName>
    </employee>
    <employee id='2'>
        <Profile_Name>Admin</Profile_Name>
        <UserName>USER</UserName>
    </employee>
    <employee id='3'>
      <Deleted/>
        <Profile_Name>Admin</Profile_Name>
        <UserName>user</UserName>
    </employee>
    <employee id='4'>
        <Profile_Name>Adminnn</Profile_Name>
        <UserName>userrrr</UserName>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

**the Xpath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
<employee id="1">
   <Profile_Name>admin</Profile_Name>
   <UserName>user</UserName>
</employee>
<employee id="2">
   <Profile_Name>Admin</Profile_Name>
   <UserName>USER</UserName>
</employee>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the translate in the wrong place.  The XPath expression your code generates will test something like

```
Profile_Name[last()][translate(.,'ABCDE...', 'abcde...')] = 'foo'
```

i.e. it will find the last `Profile_Name` element, check that that element has a non-empty value, and then compare that value (e.g. `Foo`) to the string `foo`.  Instead, you need

```
translate(Profile_Name[last()],'ABCDE...', 'abcde...') = 'foo'
```

to do the comparison on the translated value rather than the raw one.  The complete expression should be something like

```
 var xpath = "/employees/employee[not(Deleted)][translate(Profile_Name[last()],'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='" + ProfileName.ToLower() + "' or translate(UserName[last()],'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='" + UserName.ToLower() + "']";
```

Comment: I updated it to 

 `var xpath = "/employees/employee[not(Deleted)][translate([Profile_Name[last()],'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='" + ProfileName.ToLower() + "']"
                                + " or [translate(UserName[last()],'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='" + UserName.ToLower() + "']]";` but it still doesn't work

Comment: @HebaEl-Fadly you've still got too many square brackets.  I've edited in what I think should be the correct expression in full.

Answer (score 0):

.NET XSLT implementation allows to write custom managed functions in the stylesheet. For lower-case() it can be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:utils="urn:myExtension" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <msxsl:script implements-prefix="utils" language="C#">
    <![CDATA[
      public string ToLower(string stringValue)
      {
        string result = String.Empty;

        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
        {
          result = stringValue.ToLower(); 
        }

        return result;
      }
    ]]>
  </msxsl:script>

  <!-- using of our custom function -->
  <lowercaseValue>
    <xsl:value-of select="utils:ToLower($myParam)"/>
  </lowercaseValue>
```

Assume, that can be slow, but still acceptable.

Do not forget to enable embedded scripts support for transform:

```cs
// Create the XsltSettings object with script enabled.
XsltSettings xsltSettings = new XsltSettings(false, true);

XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

// Load stylesheet
xslt.Load(xsltPath, xsltSettings, new XmlUrlResolver());
```